# what is range image data means?(*.abs)

Tags: 3d, face-recognition

I'm a beginner and I faced some problems when I read a 3d face recognition paper, is range image the result of 3D reconstruction systems? is range image equals to .abs files? Besides, the most important, what is the meaning of x, y, z in .abs files? and can we transform a *.wrl file to *.abs, or reverse?

example of *.abs files:（data of x axis seems like some masks, and z seems like the depth）

`480 rows
640 columns
pixels (flag X Y Z):
0 0 1 1...`